# Spring config create fake bean to satisfy dependency for testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have an external dependency library from where I use some @Service beans. For testing I don't need them, but when I load the app context I need to create them to satisfy the dependency.

Example:
Service layer:

```
 @Service
 public class MyService{
   private ExternalLibraryService externalLibraryService;

   @Autowired
   public MyService(ExternalLibraryService externalLibraryService){
     this.externalLibraryService = externalLibraryService;
   }
    ......

 }
```

Weblayer:

```
  @Endpoint
  public class WebService{
    private MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    public WebService(MyService myService){
     this.myService = myService;
    }

    .......
  }
```

Test Weblayer:

```
 @ComponentScan("mypackages..")
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = WebConfig.class)
 public class WebServiceConfigTest {

 //dummy ExternalLibraryService to satisfy the dependency
 @Bean
 public ExternalLibraryService externalLibraryService(){
   return new ExternalLibraryService(whatever dependency other services needed);
 }
  .......
  }
```

Question: Is there any possibility to provide the external dependency bean as a fake mock bean out of the box, and not create it by hand? Example: maybe an annotation somethign like we do in testst with @Mock?
If i don't create this the app context initialization will fail because of the needed dependency injection.

Comment: Did you try @MockBean

Comment: It works with MockBean, the problem is: that it also wants all the dependencies that bean needs to be created. Example: MockBean(ExternalLibraryService.class) and for example if this needs a DataSource, I need to add ther DataSource.class too into MockBean. And if DataSource need another bean I need to provide that too. Anything simpler to just Mock that bean? I don't even care if that mock have a real instance. it is just to satisfy the dependency.

Comment: 'I need to add ther DataSource.class too into MockBean' - you don't need to add anything to a mock bean.

Comment: I found it, my bad, actually i noticed into a scanner that I actually scann the package with the external service too, and the need was nto because of the mock bean, was because the service actually created by the Spring Scanner. My bad.